# Can we set `Cronjob` to run on Particular date once a year?

Tags: linux, cron, shell

Requirement: I have shell script for updating security patches on Linux servers which has to run on maintenance timings/windows.

What we have tried as suggested here:

We are trying to edit `/etc/crontab` file as below:

```
30 13 16 * * root [[ $(date "+%Y") == 2020 ]] && /path/to/shellscript
```

Issues:
We are not able to execute above cron job:

o/p in logs:

```
CROND[24576]: (root) CMD ([[ $(date "+)
```

I am sure I am missing something in syntax of the cronjob but not sure what is that.

Please help me in resolving the issue.